# Differentiability at a Point when all Partial Derivatives are Discontinuous at that point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f: R^n\to R^m$ n > 1 s.t. all the partial derivatives are discontinuous at point a. Is the function differentiable at a? I would think not however, I know of an example in R that works, so I am wondering how this works with the linear operator of differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f$ be your example in one variable. Think about $f(x)+f(y).$